# Python dynamical, multithread variable not working

Tags: python, post, python-requests, multiprocessing

Good day guys! I am only newbie in Python and trying to write first code to post multipart data in 5 threads with dynamic variables, example i have 5 threads, in start i have integer 3000, in 1 thread i got 3000-1=2999, in next thread i got 2999-1=2998 and etc, can someone please look what wrong in my code?

```
  import requests
from multiprocessing import Pool
if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(1)
url = 'http://httpbin.org/post'
cookies = {'PHPSESSID': '2a55b01f46b3c7e5764b70666ac81cae'}
headers = {"user-agent":"undefined"}
data=(
        ('o_id', (None, '3732')),
        ('p_owner', (None, '3732')),
        ('p_name', (None, '1')),
        ('p_desc', (None, 'null')),
        ('save', (None, '')),
)
def make_request(id):
    requests.post(url, cookies=cookies, verify=False, headers=headers, files=data)
print(p.map(make_request, range(3000, 0, -1)))
```

NameError: name 'p' is not defined

Comment: Multiprocessing is not the same thing as threading.

Comment: as i said i am only newbie here, sry if smth wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code, it looks like `p` is defined in `if __name__ == '__main__':`

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(1) // p is defined in this statement as it is intended. python depends on indents to map code.
url = 'http://httpbin.org/post'
cookies = {'PHPSESSID': '2a55b01f46b3c7e5764b70666ac81cae'}
headers = {"user-agent":"undefined"}
data=(
        ('o_id', (None, '3732')),
        ('p_owner', (None, '3732')),
        ('p_name', (None, '1')),
        ('p_desc', (None, 'null')),
        ('save', (None, '')),
)
def make_request(id):
    requests.post(url, cookies=cookies, verify=False, headers=headers, files=data)
print(p.map(make_request, range(3000, 0, -1)))
```

i *assume* what you wanted to do is to have everything inside of that main statement, in which case, *all* of the code would need to be indented. like so:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(1) // in this example, all of the code is indented, which will allow it all to work.
    url = 'http://httpbin.org/post'
    cookies = {'PHPSESSID': '2a55b01f46b3c7e5764b70666ac81cae'}
    headers = {"user-agent":"undefined"}
    data=(
        ('o_id', (None, '3732')),
        ('p_owner', (None, '3732')),
        ('p_name', (None, '1')),
        ('p_desc', (None, 'null')),
        ('save', (None, '')),
    )
    def make_request(id):
        requests.post(url, cookies=cookies, verify=False, headers=headers, files=data)
    print(p.map(make_request, range(3000, 0, -1)))
```

Comment: Thanks for ur response! So i got problems there, now its saying
`AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'make_request' on <module '__mp_main__' `

Comment: i need make         ('p_owner', (None, '3732')),  dynamical, like new thread  - 3732-1=3731 i am so bad in python sry